# How to control what jQuery version to include, with wp_enqueue_script

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I'm using a script that is based on jQuery, so I'm not enqueue-ing jQuery directly, but via passing it in the array of dependent scripts:

```
 wp_enqueue_script("jquery-plugin-name",'http://hostname.il/blogname/wp-content/themes/twentyten/js/jquery-plugin-name.js', array('jquery'), '1');
```

This is loading jQuery  v1.4.4, and it weighs 76kb, which seems very heavy, although the file looks compressed.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there I way in which I can make it load the latest version of jQuery?
2. How can I make sure that the loaded file if minified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the size of the minified jQuery nowadays :)

You can load the latest from Google:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"), false, '1.8.2');
```

Please keep in mind that this can cause issues moving forward, as you are forcing WordPress to load a certain version of jQuery instead of the version bundled with it. There are plugins out there that may be better suited for your needs, like [WP JQuery Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-jquery-plus/), which make sure to load the same version number as WordPress does, but with the benefit of loading it from Google.

Comment: Don't forget to conditionally exclude this from admin area, it uses jQuery a lot and doesn't like it swapped for another version.

Comment: Thanks. But how come this site has a much smaller jQuery file?

Comment: It's older version. I wouldn't say it's much smaller, 10-15K?

Comment: @One, From what I see with JSView, the jQuery in WPSE is version 1.5.2 (mine is 1.4.4), and it weighs 29kb as opposed to my 76 kb. Thanks

Comment: it's the same size, but the server probably serves it [compressed](http://www.techiepark.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-gzip-compression-in-apache-server-to-speed-up-website/)

Comment: **Never, never, never modify the core-bundled version of jQuery.**

Comment: **Almost everybody uses the incorrect handle**
WordPress actually uses the jquery-core handle, not jquery: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/91da29d9afaa664eb84e1261ebb916b18a362aa9/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L226 **See my answer below** for better implementation and handling. My code excludes the WP Admin and WP Customizer for compatibility reasons.

Comment: in which file do i need to include this code?

Answer (score 5):

I have developed a plugin for this specific problem. This plugin doesn't mess with WordPress jQuery as it is only loaded in the front-end. See: [jQuery Manager for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-manager/)

> ### Why yet another jQuery Updater / Manager / Developer / Debugging tool?
>
> Because none of the developer tools lets you select a specific
>   version of jQuery and/or jQuery Migrate. Providing both the production
>   and the minified version. See features below!
>
> ✅ Only executed in the front-end, **doesn't interfere with WordPress
>   admin/backend and WP customizer** (for compatibility reasons) See:
>   https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45130 and
>   https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37110
>
> ✅ **Turn on/off** jQuery and/or jQuery Migrate
>
> ✅ Activate a **specific version** of jQuery and/or jQuery Migrate
>
> And much more! The code is open source, so you could study
>   it, learn from it and contribute.

### Almost everybody uses the incorrect handle

WordPress actually uses the jquery-core handle, not jquery:

> https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/91da29d9afaa664eb84e1261ebb916b18a362aa9/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L226
>
> ```
> // jQuery
> $scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate' ), '1.12.4' );
> $scripts->add( 'jquery-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.12.4' );
> $scripts->add( 'jquery-migrate', "/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate$suffix.js", array(), '1.4.1' );
> ```
>
> The **jquery** handle is just an alias to load **jquery-core** with **jquery-migrate**
> See more info about aliases: [wp_register_script multiple identifiers?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/283828/wp-register-script-multiple-identifiers)

### The correct way to do it

In my example below I use the official jQuery CDN at https://code.jquery.com I also use **script_loader_tag** so that I could add some CDN attributes.
You could use the following code:

```
// Front-end not excuted in the wp admin and the wp customizer (for compatibility reasons)
// See: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45130 and https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37110
function wp_jquery_manager_plugin_front_end_scripts() {
    $wp_admin = is_admin();
    $wp_customizer = is_customize_preview();

    // jQuery
    if ( $wp_admin || $wp_customizer ) {
        // echo 'We are in the WP Admin or in the WP Customizer';
        return;
    }
    else {
        // Deregister WP core jQuery, see https://github.com/Remzi1993/wp-jquery-manager/issues/2 and https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/91da29d9afaa664eb84e1261ebb916b18a362aa9/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L226
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // the jquery handle is just an alias to load jquery-core with jquery-migrate
        // Deregister WP jQuery
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-core' );
        // Deregister WP jQuery Migrate
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-migrate' );

        // Register jQuery in the head
        wp_register_script( 'jquery-core', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', array(), null, false );

        /**
         * Register jquery using jquery-core as a dependency, so other scripts could use the jquery handle
         * see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/283828/wp-register-script-multiple-identifiers
         * We first register the script and afther that we enqueue it, see why:
         * https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/when-should-i-use-wp-register-script-with-wp-enqueue-script-vs-just-wp-enque
         * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653993/what-is-diffrence-between-wp-enqueue-script-and-wp-register-script
         */
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core' ), null, false );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_jquery_manager_plugin_front_end_scripts' );


function add_jquery_attributes( $tag, $handle ) {
    if ( 'jquery-core' === $handle ) {
        return str_replace( "type='text/javascript'", "type='text/javascript' integrity='sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=' crossorigin='anonymous'", $tag );
    }
    return $tag;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_jquery_attributes', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Nice plugin!  Is there any reason it hasn't been updated in 10 months?  Are you abandoning it?  There is still a "experimental" feature in the settings, so I am concerned about using it for the final solution if you aren't planning to update the plugin.

Comment: @OldGreg I was looking for other co-miantainers and the main reason is that I don't work for a WordPress development agency anymore and I went to React for a while. Now I'm studying Software Engineering at a university for applied sciences and don't have any time to do open source in my free time, especially such a large project where I was the only developer and maintainer.

Comment: @OldGreg Also since WordPress 5 it's not needed anymore. My plugin was always a stopgap solution, a temporary patch. Since WordPress 5 they have updated jQuery and even included an official jQuery plugin which is on the wp.org plugins repository. I took too much time to develop and maintain a jQuery developer and testing tool.

Answer (score 3):

**Do not modify the version of jQuery enqueued by WordPress.**

Just don't do it. Core depends on a specific version. Themes and Plugins depend on a certain version. That certain version is *the version bundled with a given version of WordPress*.

If you need to perform script minification, compression, or concatenation, you can certainly do that (you can roll your own, or use a Plugin, such as [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache), to do it for you.)

But as you can see: if you're got a 46kB file, [you're already dealing with some combination of minification and compression](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/jquery-size).