# When should I use wp_register_script() with wp_enqueue_script() vs just wp_enqueue_script()?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I'm having trouble understanding when you need to use `wp_register_script()`. Currently, I just use something like:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue' ) );
function enqueue() {
    $handle = 'some-handle';
    $js = 'http://example.com/my.js';
    wp_register_script( $handle, $js );
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle );
}
```

I've done a lot of reading (Codex, blogs, etc.), but can't quite understand when I should register first, or when I should just enqueue. As an example, I noticed *TwentyTwelve* doesn't register any styles or scripts, it just enqueues them.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The [`wp_register_script()` Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) literally says:

> A safe way of registering javascripts in WordPress for later use with `wp_enqueue_script()`.

This means, if you want to register your scripts, but not directly load them in your pages, you can register the files once, and then load them when you need them.

For example:

You have a switch statement which loads some functionality, but two of three cases needs a particular JavaScript file, and one doesn't. You can enqueue the script every time, which costs more resources, or just enqueue the script when you need it:

```
...
wp_register_script( 'my-handy-javascript', ... );
...
switch( $somevar ) {
    case 'value':
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-handy-javascript' ); // needs the file
        ...
    break;
    case 'value2':
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-handy-javascript' ); // needs the file
        ...
    break;
    default:
    case 'value3': // doesn't needs the file
        ...
    break;
}
```

It is not necessary to register a script and then enqueue them, but it can provide some logic in your code if you register all the scripts you need somewhere in your `functions.php` instead of everywhere in your code.

The Codex also tells the following:

> Use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action to call this function, or `admin_enqueue_scripts` to call it on the admin side.

This means that if you want to enqueue your script on the frond-end **and** in the back-end, you can register a script once, and then load it on the front-end with `wp_enqueue_script` and in the back-end with `admin_enqueue_script`.
This way you won't have the same enqueue recourse twice in one theme, plugin, widget or whatever.

Comment: Thank you. That cleared it up a lot. So, do you think that TwentyTwelve doesn't bother to register first since it's going to load them for sure?

Comment: That sure could be a possibility. I don't know how the Twenty Twelve theme is build since I never use it, but they sure will have their reasons to `enqueue` in stead of `register`.

Comment: The way I see it, the register function is by no means technically required, it just exists for convenience: it saves some typing work. If that is true, then this should be explicitly stated in the documentation.

Comment: In that sense, I disagree with "You can enqueue the script every time, wich costs more resources, or just enqueue the script when you need it". In your example code, you could remove the register call and instead have multiple *equivalent* full-fledged (with $src arg) calls to `wp_enqueue_style()`. This would just be more typing effort, but **not** result in larger resource requirements. Correct?

Comment: So, this is meaning, for load script or css file, is necessary using `wp_enqueue_scripts` or `wp_enqueue_style` function, with or without register function?

Comment: One point which has been left out by all explanations so far is, that you can use `wp_register_script()` to just register a script so it can be used as a dependency for other scripts and only be loaded with them, without ever being enqueued directly.

Comment: Even though this explains it well I would recommend to read [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124381/77054) as well.

Comment: What's ridiculous is that you have to *register* the script on e.g. `wp_enqueue_scripts`, which doesn't make sense if you want to be nice and register all your stuff to make it available for everything later (such as dependency). Noooo... You have to use one or more of the same 3 hooks (one for front office, one for back office, and one for login screen). So, you gona have `wp_register_script()` followed by the usage of that registered script anyway. Not so elegant now, is it? Which IMO beats the point of having 2 separate functions.

Comment: FYI, `admin_enqueue_script` doesn't appear to be a WordPress function/hook. But `admin_enqueue_scripts` is a WordPress hook that can load enqueued JavaScript of CSS files - see:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/

Answer (score 11):

IMHO the main advantage of using `wp_register_script` before `wp_enqueue_scripts` is illustrated in the following paragraph from [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/#more-information):

> Scripts that have been pre-registered using wp_register_script() do
>   not need to be manually enqueued using wp_enqueue_script() if they are
>   listed as a dependency of another script that is enqueued. WordPress
>   will automatically include the registered script before it includes
>   the enqueued script that lists the registered script’s handle as a
>   dependency.

If you believe you don't need this (e.g. because you are 100% sure that your script won't be involved in any dependency) you probably can go directly with `wp_enqueue_scripts`, without a preliminary `wp_register_script`.

Comment: I think the laso paragraph (about not needing the register if you " are 100% sure that your script won't be involved in any dependency" is wrong. I think the right thing is that you do not need to register if you are sure that you are going to load your script anyway. - enqueuing implicitly also registers your script so it can be depended on by other scripts even if you only enqueued it.

Answer (score 11):

I have gone through some articles and come to the following conclusion. I think it helps.

1. Registering any scripts using `wp_register_script()` is just registering; not loading it. The registered script will not be loaded until it is enqueued using `wp_enqueue_script()`.
2. We don’t need to register and enqueue each of the scripts simultaneously. We should just enqueue. Registering is not mandatory as the `wp_enqueue_script()` function automatically registers the script.
3. But we do need to register while we are in any of the following situations:

   a. Suppose we need a script to load into more than one place like once in front-end and once in back-end (admin page). Now we can register the script just once. And then enqueue it in front-end and back-end individually. Look, enqueueing means loading. Registering doesn’t mean loading. In case we don’t register it, it will be automatically registered as many times as we enqueue it. On the other hand, if we register it once, it will be registered once, no matter how many times we enqueue it.

   b. If we want to use a script as a dependency of other scripts, then we don’t need to enqueue it with `wp_enqueue_script()`. Just register it with `wp_register_script()`. And it will be automatically enqueued when we use it’s handle name as a dependency of other scripts enqueued with `wp_enqueue_script()`.

   c. If we want the script to be loaded when necessary rather than to be loaded at once, we can just register it for later use. The use case has been shown above.

N.B. As far as I am convinced, the same conclusion can be drawn for the CSS stylesheets. I mean to say that we can use `wp_register_style()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` in the same way.

Note that the conclusion drawn here reflects my own deduction. If I’m wrong, please correct me. And you might have reached a different and much better conclusion. If thing’s so, then please let us know.  Who knows? Perhaps yours is the best. As the saying goes, *“As many tenets, as many ways to salvation.”* :)

https://ansrthemeaction.blogspot.com/2019/11/wpregisterscript-when-to-use.html

Comment: Your explanation is the best I've read. Now I understand why it's important to register scripts. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much @Jee

Comment: This is the most helpful answer I've ever read. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much @ThiagoSantos