# Enqueue core jQuery in the footer?

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I have this in my `functions.php` file and I can't get jQuery to load in the footer. The `includes` file loads in the footer fine, though. What else do I need to do?

```
function starter_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'starter-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '', '', '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'includes', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/min/includes.min.js', '', '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'starter_scripts' );
```

Comment: If you're doing this for performance reasons, you could consider adding `defer` to your script tags instead: https://matthewhorne.me/defer-async-wordpress-scripts/

Comment: WP dev here, I made a plugin to deal with this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-manager/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To do that you will first have to deregister your jQuery script and then register again.
If you use jQuery comes with WordPress then following is the function your are looking for.

```
function starter_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', includes_url( '/js/jquery/jquery.js' ), false, NULL, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'starter-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'includes', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/min/includes.min.js', '', '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'starter_scripts' );
```

If you use Google CDN hosted version of jQuery then let me know I will modify this code for Google CDN URL.

Comment: I Tried this and still in the footer, any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean? The solution is about moving jQuery to footer.

Comment: You might also need to check is_admin() to avoid making changes to the backend jQuery, after all we only really need to optimise the frontend of our sites :)

Comment: @TimMalone - actually, you don't - `wp_enqueue_scripts` is used only on front end while `admin_enqueue_scripts` is used for back end

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't work because a plugin add its script with "in_footer" parameter false. This cause the jquery script to move to head.

Comment: I think this solution is actually horrible. Are the version tags are removed with this. What is this starter-style and that is this includes.min.js and what has it to do with jQuery.

Comment: @redanimalwar starter-style and includes files are directly from the question.

Comment: @Roberthue I'm still looking for more devs who like to help maintain an open sourche project, see: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-manager/ and https://github.com/Remzi1993/jquery-manager this plugin / project should help users to use the latest version of jQuery with a simple click.

Answer (score 60):

Here's another option which avoids having to de-register and re-register:

```
/**
 * Move jQuery to the footer. 
 */
function wpse_173601_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_scripts()->add_data( 'jquery', 'group', 1 );
    wp_scripts()->add_data( 'jquery-core', 'group', 1 );
    wp_scripts()->add_data( 'jquery-migrate', 'group', 1 );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_173601_enqueue_scripts' );
```

This solution [mimics WordPress core](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php#L149) by setting the `group` to `1`, which is how WordPress determines if a script should be in the footer or not (I'm not aware of the reasoning for `1`, as @jgraup noted in the comments it seems a bit arbitrary).

Comment: Interesting. It looks like `wp_register_script` uses `add_data( $handle, 'group', 1 )` to move scripts into the footer. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php#L117 - Could you expand on why that is? Glancing at your code, 'group' seems a bit arbitrary. But I can see in https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php#L231 how it's used in WP_Scripts->`do_item` later. Either way, this would seem to be the least destructive answer.

Comment: I hope someone can comment further on these three  upvoted answers.  All are different and require some knowledge of WP.  Because google requires these scripts to be below the fold, this is an important topic.

Comment: Best answer! **Note**: it works since WordPress 4.2.0 and use it in functions.php in hook 'wp_enqueue_scripts' callback

Comment: Hi I tried the above approach, but it didn't worked. Can anyone help?

Comment: @iSaumya You might have to add some details on why it didn't work / what happened. That's a pretty cryptic request! See also the other new answer, and keep in mind this answer still needs to be wrapped in a function and filter call.

Comment: @tim I've tried that bit it is still not pushing the scrip to footer. That's what happened.

Comment: @iSaumya I added some additional detail for you, I hope this helps!

Comment: WordPress uses such an old version of jQuery, at this rate it is better to deregister and register to the newest version.

Comment: This is so good! Thank you so much. But, worth noting is as @tehlivi states - WP uses an old version of jQuery - consider deregistering and registering a newer version.

Comment: This code returned me a 500 error. I have WordPress 4.9.9

Comment: @MarcoPanichi perhaps you have a conflicting theme or plugin? Can you try it on a brand new installation of wordpress with no plugins added and using the default theme?

Comment: @MatthewBoynes I think you are right. On an other installation it works.

Comment: @MatthewBoynes I'm still looking for more devs who like to help maintain an open sourche project, see: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-manager/ and https://github.com/Remzi1993/jquery-manager this plugin / project should help users to use the latest version of jQuery with a simple click.

Comment: This works but `1` is a "magic number". If it changes this code will break. And unfortunately we don't know what it is, so we can't replace it with a constant. Does anyone actually know what it refers to??

Comment: Parameter **1** answers the question "Should we move the script to the footer?" in the function - It means "true" I think.

Comment: works pretty good in wordpress 5.6 thanks man :)

Answer (score 24):

**A better solution:**

```
add_action( 'wp_default_scripts', 'move_jquery_into_footer' );

function move_jquery_into_footer( $wp_scripts ) {

    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    $wp_scripts->add_data( 'jquery', 'group', 1 );
    $wp_scripts->add_data( 'jquery-core', 'group', 1 );
    $wp_scripts->add_data( 'jquery-migrate', 'group', 1 );
}
```

**Why its better then the accepted answer IMO**

1. Changes it at the very core not at a later stage where other things might already messed with it.
2. The version string it kept in place and not removed!
3. It does not unregister and reregister a script but it just sets the group value that is essentially the same as if the script would be registered with `$footer = true`.

**About not doing this to the admin**

If plugins add inline jquery to the wp_head it will fail when jquery is not loaded at that point, so I suggest you avoid that until you have millions editing your site and you try to performance optimize your admin. This is true for frontend as well so you should watch out for bad coded themes or plugins that assume jquery in the head by using inline jQuery code. WP and plugins register other scripts to the admin head with jquery in deps so it would not work anyway I think.

**About it not working**

You need to be aware that if any other script is loaded to the head that has jQuery in its dependencies, it will also make jQuery load in the head right before itself. And this is good and expected, the reason the wp_enqueue system exists. This means you will learn soon if you use a few plugins that one of them will require cause jquery to the head. It the the default for enqueued scripts, sadly.

**Radical Solution**

I think it will brake any inline JS that assumes jquery but should that should be rare. This will force **all scripts** to the footer regardless of how they are enqueued.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_to_footer' );

function js_to_footer() {
  remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts' );
  remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9 );
  remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1 );
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question and has some good points to chew on there's too much noise (fluff?) in the answer and is very similar to the previously posted answers with minor code improvements. It may be more well received if it were edited and slimmed down into a more informational version. There's also no real need to call out specific users or answers ( as they may not exist for whatever reason in the future ).

Comment: You call a completely unmentioned and probably better then anything mentioned in other answers "minor code improvements". Well thats simply untrue. Also I did not "call out" anyone, I just mentioned facts that I know to improve coding style and educate readers about it to make them write better code. Seriously I did take quite some time to write the best answer here to far and this is what I get for it.

Comment: The other answers mention nothing about others scripts forcing the jQuery to the head, in fact my answer takes the confusion away from people who don't know why its not working. None of the others answers mention the potential risks ...

Comment: This code (as the code of the answer above) returned me a 500 error. I have WordPress 4.9.9

Comment: Hard to believe that this code is causing a 500, you probably have made a mistake in implementing this in your code. This is not really the right place to ask and your outdated WP version is hardly enough information.

Comment: @NextGenThemes I'm still looking for more devs who like to help maintain an open sourche project, see: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-manager/ and https://github.com/Remzi1993/jquery-manager this plugin / project should help users to use the latest version of jQuery with a simple click.

Comment: Hey man, great your radical solution, is what I was looking for, maybe your answer is somehow similar to the above but it is clearer, cheers

Answer (score 2):

I have developed a plugin for this specific problem. This plugin doesn't mess with WordPress jQuery as it is only loaded in the front-end. See: [jQuery Manager for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-manager/)

> ### Why yet another jQuery Updater / Manager / Developer / Debugging tool?
>
> Because none of the developer tools lets you select a specific
>   version of jQuery and/or jQuery Migrate. Providing both the compressed minified / production 
>   and the uncompressed / development version. See features below!
>
> ✅ Only executed in the front-end, **doesn't interfere with WordPress
>   admin/backend and WP customizer** (for compatibility reasons) See:
>   https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45130 and
>   https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37110
>
> ✅ **Turn on/off** jQuery and/or jQuery Migrate
>
> ✅ Activate a **specific version** of jQuery and/or jQuery Migrate
>
> And much more! The code is open source, so you could study
>   it, learn from it and contribute.

### Almost everybody uses the incorrect handle

WordPress actually uses the jquery-core handle, not jquery:

> https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f84ab5e19f0038a3abec71821c9b8f47a4272942/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L1017
>
> ```
> // jQuery
> $scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate' ), '1.12.4-wp' );
> $scripts->add( 'jquery-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.12.4-wp' );
> $scripts->add( 'jquery-migrate', "/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate$suffix.js", array(), '1.4.1' );
> ```
>
> The **jquery** handle is just an alias to load **jquery-core** with **jquery-migrate**
> See more info about aliases: [wp_register_script multiple identifiers?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/283828/wp-register-script-multiple-identifiers)

### The correct way to do it

In my example below I use the official jQuery CDN at https://code.jquery.com I also use **script_loader_tag** so that I could add some CDN attributes.
You could use the following code:

```
// Front-end not excuted in the wp admin and the wp customizer (for compatibility reasons)
// See: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45130 and https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37110
function wp_jquery_manager_plugin_front_end_scripts() {
    $wp_admin = is_admin();
    $wp_customizer = is_customize_preview();

    // jQuery
    if ( $wp_admin || $wp_customizer ) {
        // echo 'We are in the WP Admin or in the WP Customizer';
        return;
    }
    else {
        // Deregister WP core jQuery, see https://github.com/Remzi1993/wp-jquery-manager/issues/2 and https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/91da29d9afaa664eb84e1261ebb916b18a362aa9/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L226
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // the jquery handle is just an alias to load jquery-core with jquery-migrate
        // Deregister WP jQuery
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-core' );
        // Deregister WP jQuery Migrate
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-migrate' );

        // Register jQuery in the head
        wp_register_script( 'jquery-core', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', array(), null, false );

        /**
         * Register jquery using jquery-core as a dependency, so other scripts could use the jquery handle
         * see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/283828/wp-register-script-multiple-identifiers
         * We first register the script and afther that we enqueue it, see why:
         * https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/when-should-i-use-wp-register-script-with-wp-enqueue-script-vs-just-wp-enque
         * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653993/what-is-diffrence-between-wp-enqueue-script-and-wp-register-script
         */
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core' ), null, false );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_jquery_manager_plugin_front_end_scripts' );


function add_jquery_attributes( $tag, $handle ) {
    if ( 'jquery-core' === $handle ) {
        return str_replace( "type='text/javascript'", "type='text/javascript' integrity='sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=' crossorigin='anonymous'", $tag );
    }
    return $tag;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_jquery_attributes', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This places jQuery in the head (as per your own inline comment) and is not an answer for OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "myscripts");

function myscripts() { 
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' , '', array(), true); //true for footer
   wp_enqueue_script( 'someScript-js', 'https://domain.com/someScript.js' , '', '', true );
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Hey only change your code to like this

```
function starter_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'starter-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'includes', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/min/includes.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'starter_scripts' );
```

i think it work fine

add this lines into your functions.php file

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
```

then it add script into footer

Comment: This puts jQuery in the head. I need it in the footer.

Comment: Hey Desi please check the edited answer I think it help you

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a terrible idea -- you've effectively prevented _anything_ from loading scripts in the header, not just jQuery, and might be double-enqueuing scripts (haven't looked that deeply).  In fact, you probably only need the `remove_action` / `add_action` part if you're going to do it this way.

Comment: Indeed terrible idea, don't do this!