# True parameter but jquery register in header and not in the footer with wp_register_script

Tags: functions, jquery, actions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I want to register jquery.js in the footer, but even with the true parameter it registers in the header.

Here is the code. The other scripts are registered in the footer. Only jquery does not.

```
function mysite_scripts() {

wp_deregister_script('jquery');

wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/libs/jquery-3.1.1.min.js', array(), "3.1.1", true );

wp_register_script( 'plugins-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/plugins.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

wp_register_script( 'main-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array( 'jquery', 'plugins-script' ), false, true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'main-script' ); 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mysite_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you. try with enqueue instead of registering it.

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/libs/jquery-3.1.1.min.js', array(), "3.1.1", true );
```

Comment: Still in the header

Comment: this answer might help.. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173601/enqueue-core-jquery-in-the-footer