# Move Jquery.js to Footer

Tags: php, jquery, javascript

I want to move jquery.js from header to footer. I have tried following code:

```
//Remove jQuery Default
function replace_jquery() {
 if (!is_admin()) {
 wp_deregister_script('jquery');
 }
}
add_action('init', 'replace_jquery');

//Load on Footer
add_action('wp_footer', 'jquery_code');
function jquery_code(){
?>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
<?php
};
```

The issue is that If I run first piece of above code, js files of my theme are removed with jquery.js. Because theme's static js files is calling via `array( 'jquery' )` attributes.

I just want to move jquery only from header to footer.

**NOTE:** I have tried other suggestions on Stackexchange but none of them didn't work on my blog. (Such us: [Enqueue core jQuery in the footer?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173601/enqueue-core-jquery-in-the-footer))

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deregister `jQuery`, you have to register it again. Try this code

**UPDATE:** You have to deregister `jQuery` first (first part of your code), so the final code should be:

```
//Load on Footer
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_jquery');
function register_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); // remove original jQuery
    wp_register_script( // add custom jQuery in footer
       'jquery', 
       'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js',
       array(), // dependencies
       null, // version
       true); // load in footer?
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

But it's NOT RECOMMENDED to load custom jquery in wordpress.

Comment: Thank your for your help friend :)
But still jquery is loaded on header. This situation is related to theme codes?

Comment: If I add below code instead of yours, it can create any issue?

//Load on Footer
add_action('wp_footer', 'jquery_code');
function jquery_code(){
?>
AUTO-DEREGISTERED THEME JS CODES HERE
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
<?php
};

Comment: Yes, because jQuery will be not registered and the other scripts (dependencies) will be not work. One thing about my answer - don't forget to deregister jquery first (first part of your code - `Remove jQuery Default`, and after that - my code.

Comment: @SerdarKoçak if my answer helped you, please mark my answer ;)