# No data received

Tags: jquery, javascript

When I use the wp_register_script() and wp_enqueue_script() to load the jquery  for the wordpress I got "no data received result with other information like this :

Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
My code to load the jquery is

```
function theme_script(){
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

        wp_register_script('jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/sliderengine/jquery.js');
        wp_enqueue_scripts('jquery');

        wp_register_script('amazingslider',get_template_directory_uri().'/sliderengine/amazingslider.js',array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_scripts('amazingslider');    

        wp_register_script('initslider-1',get_template_directory_uri().'/sliderengine/initslider-1.js',array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_scripts('initslider-1');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_script');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You are confusing `wp_enqeue_script` function and `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. It should be:

```
function theme_script(){
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_register_script('jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/sliderengine/jquery.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('amazingslider',get_template_directory_uri().'/sliderengine/amazingslider.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('amazingslider');    

    wp_register_script('initslider-1',get_template_directory_uri().'/sliderengine/initslider-1.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('initslider-1');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_script');
```

Comment: @cybmeta - Any reason why you don't just do this with one call to `wp_enqueue_script`? Unless the OP plans to enqueue the scripts from other files or deregister them, isn't it easier to not worry about first registering the scripts?

Comment: I don't know the plans of the OP in that matter and I usually register the scripts and styles to make them available for easy use anywhere, so I just fix the errors in the code. I like this [read](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/when-should-i-use-wp-register-script-with-wp-enqueue-script-vs-just-wp-enque).