# link to JS library using wp_enqueue_scripts not working

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I've added the following code to `functions.php` of my activated child theme:

```
function fullpagejs() {
    $slimscroll = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/fullPage.js-master/vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js' ;
    wp_register_script('fullpage-slimscroll', $slimscroll, false, null);
    //some more files will be added here later
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "fullpagejs");
```

However when I check the page source, I can't find the script `jquery.slimscroll.min.js` registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not only register the script, but also enqueue it after that, like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('fullpage-slimscroll');
```

Comment: Pleased to help you. Could you accept the answer by clicking on the "check" to the left. So everybody knows this question doesn't need attention anymore.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to register the script before enqueueing.

Comment: @Max Possibly, but there could also be reasons to do both: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/when-should-i-use-wp-register-script-with-wp-enqueue-script-vs-just-wp-enque

Comment: @MaxYudin according to WordPress, 'Registering scripts is technically not necessary, but highly recommended nonetheless.' so you're right, not needed but as the script has some dependencies (jquery) I will add it.

Comment: @cjbj sure, I'm a noobie so I wasnt sure how to signal the code worked. I've ticked it now :)

Comment: @LuizaRios If the script has some dependencies you have to point it out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are registering the script instead on enqueueing.

Also, slimScroll depends on jQuery. So you have to point it out explicitly.

```
function fullpagejs() {
    $slimscroll = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/fullPage.js-master/vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js' ;
    wp_enqueue_script( // see here
        'fullpage-slimscroll',
        $slimscroll,
        array('jquery'), // dependency
        null
    );
    //some more files will be added here later
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "fullpagejs");
```

Comment: You're right Max, I hadn't read your answer when I replied to the other one above. In fact, to make things harder, this scripts has another dependency which I also have to add to the website, so here's how the final code is looking:

Comment: `code` function fullpagejs() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js'); 
    $slimscroll = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/fullPage.js-master/vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js' ;
    wp_register_script('fullpage-slimscroll', $slimscroll, array ('jquery', 'jquery-ui'), null);
    wp_enqueue_script('fullpage-slimscroll');
    //some more files will be added here later
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "fullpagejs");`code`

Comment: @LuizaRios If you want to use external libraries you have [deregister](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) native WP libraries first. `jQuery` and `jQuery-UI` are native. See the list [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Comment: I don't want to use external libraries, I checked that list before but I couldn't find simple jquery-ui (although I did see dozens of jquery-ui-something) so I assumed this one had to be brought in manually, is that not the case? Can I just leave `code` array ('jquery', 'jquery-ui') `code` without first having to bring in the script?

Comment: @LuizaRios You had to look for `jquery-ui-core` in that list. `array ('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core')`